# How to deal with duplicate target names in reStructuredText and Sphinx?

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, doxygen, restructuredtext

Suppose, I have the following four RST files:

**index.rst**

```
.. _index:

.. documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Wed May  5 09:01:16 2021.

Welcome to X's documentation!
==================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   src/namespace_MyNamespace


Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

**namespace_MyNamespace.rst**

```
.. _namespace_MyNamespace:

===========
MyNamespace
===========

namespace
=========




Class Summary
=============
+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| :ref:`MyNamespace::MyClassOne<class_MyNamespace__MyClassOne>` | implementation of MyTemplateTest |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| :ref:`MyNamespace::MyClassTwo<class_MyNamespace__MyClassTwo>` | implementation of MyTemplateTest |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+




.. include:: class_MyNamespace__MyClassOne.rst.inc
.. include:: class_MyNamespace__MyClassTwo.rst.inc
```

**class_MyNamespace__MyClassOne.rst.inc**

```
.. _class_MyNamespace__MyClassOne:

=======================
MyNamespace::MyClassOne
=======================

class
=====


Attributes Summary
==================
+---------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| `attr_private_int`_ | attr_private_int: this is an integer attr. |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------------+

Attribute Documentation
=======================
.. _attr_private_int:

`attr_private_int`
    attr_private_int: this is an integer attr.
```

**class_MyNamespace__MyClassTwo.rst.inc**

```
.. _class_MyNamespace__MyClassTwo:

=======================
MyNamespace::MyClassTwo
=======================

class
=====


Attributes Summary
==================
+---------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| `attr_private_int`_ | attr_private_int: this is an integer attr. |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------------+

Attribute Documentation
=======================
.. _attr_private_int:

`attr_private_int`
    attr_private_int: this is an integer attr.
```

If you look closely, the two of the files have the same labels named `attr_private_int`.

So, Sphinx is giving me the following warnings:

```
reading sources... [100%] src/namespace_MyNamespace
src/class_MyNamespace__MyClassTwo.rst.inc:19: WARNING: Duplicate explicit target name: "attr_private_int".
src/class_MyNamespace__MyClassOne.rst.inc:14: WARNING: Duplicate target name, cannot be used as a unique reference: "attr_private_int".
src/class_MyNamespace__MyClassTwo.rst.inc:14: WARNING: Duplicate target name, cannot be used as a unique reference: "attr_private_int".
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You mention doxygen, but not its version, furthermore I don't see any further reference to doxygen in the question. Looks like sphinx /rst doesn't take the class scope into account.

Comment: As you have found, you cannot use targets in an include that is included more than once because the target location cannot be resolved. The workaround I use is to put the targets in the file that does the inclusion. In your case, you would need to break apart your include files into smaller chunks.